# Evaluate if code is simplified subset of JS functionality

Tags: javascript, parsing

I want to define a “Simple JS” language that’s a subset of JS functionality. Then I’d like to analyze a small JS file and evaluate if it adheres to only using Simple JS functionality. This subset would be quite limited and be an “allowlist” of functionality rather than a “blocklist”.

More specifically, I want to check that the JS file only uses “vanilla” / “basic” functionality like:

- Setting/modifying variables
- Functions

Examples of “advanced” JS functionality that would not be in the Simple JS subset include:

- Async/await
- Eval
- Networking

How would I implement such a Simple JS analyzer?

Comment: This question feels way too broad for SO. Maybe this can get you somewhere: [Open Source JavaScript Code Analysis Tools](https://www.softwaretestingmagazine.com/tools/open-source-javascript-code-analysis/)

Comment: [ESTree](//github.com/estree/estree) could be useful for this, but semantics are probably infeasible to check in general; `eval` and networking are part of that. You’d need to evaluate every possible subexpression to determine if it happens to evaluate to the function object equivalent to `eval`, while proving that side-effects from lookups (via global getters) won’t happen; if the code is written like [JSFuck](//www.jsfuck.com), this would be extremely tedious. Familiarity with the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262) is valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those things that has a lot of caveats, and is EXTREMELY hard to do securely. If Simple JS is just a fun project, then you can learn a little of how compilers work by using a library like `estree` mentioned above to generate an AST. Then you would simply traverse the AST and verify that each node is on the "allow" list, or at least not on a "deny" list.

If this will take untrusted user scripts and run them in a full JS interpreter, realize that you will **absolutely not** do it securely. Generating an AST is static analysis, but if the code can find any covert way to modify itself while running (eval as an example, but there is a lot of ways) then it will have **total access** to the full JS language.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the clear warning. This would be one of many security precautions for running user scripts. It would definitely not stand on its own. Out of curiosity, what are some other examples of the code modifying itself?

Comment: @pir I think maybe self modifying is a perhaps not exactly the right phrase, but in the security world code that generates more code is the anthesis of static code analysis, because the generated code only exists at runtime. In JS the hazard would in fact be in the program running *more* code such as with `eval`, `Function()`, or more likely some surreptitious way to indirectly cause those actions. The problem with security is that if your thing is of any consequence, adversaries are impressively intelligent practitioners of lateral thinking.

Comment: @pir The notion of self modifying code comes more from languages that allow unreasonable control over memory, such that a program could literally stuff ASM into memory and then jump right into it, or even overwrite its own ASM with new instructions. In these languages there is nothing like `eval`, but it is *sort of similar*. Anyways, I think that is where the jargon comes from.

Comment: @pir Your concept of filtering JS to some allowed subset actually is used in practice. Google uses it in a few products, one example: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/templates/sandboxed-javascript

Comment: @pir I think outfits like codesandbox and leetcode use isolation like Docker containers between sandboxes, which might be another avenue. It is difficult for malicious code to abuse the environment if it is disposable/read-only/not connected to anything!